# Magento 2 Mass Product Action module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog, massaction, product-grid

Hi magenticians I need the code of the module magento 2 which allows to add a text input when clicking on a mass action to enter a value like this example
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ? :) IF yes, would you share your code ? thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$Ids = [];
$attributes = ['name' => 'product name'];
$storeId = 0; // for admin
$productMassAction = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
$productMassAction->updateAttributes($Ids, $attributes, $storeId);
```

**---------- EDIT -------------**

`But for admin panel this gets called`

**execute() inside `app\code\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save.php`**

Comment: For mass status change and mass delete you can use these files `MassDelete.php` and `MassStatus.php`  inside `app\code\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product`

Comment: Thank you my friend, I have already managed to modify the value with this code but I am stuck in how I can add an input text to enter the new value , for example enter +20 and press apply, how to add input text and button

Comment: To make the dynamic product name from the written value in the input